# Using tic toc for benchmark MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, benchmarking

yesterday I was testing whether using a for loop for adding up elements in and array was worse than using the built-in MATLAB function sum (As far I understand this should be the case, since built-in functions are pre-compiled), however I got some weird results:

```
r = rand(1e8, 1);

tic
sum1 = 0;
for i = 1:1e8
    sum1 = sum1 + r(i);
end
t1 = toc;

tic
sum2 = sum(r);
t2 = toc;


>> t1

t1 =

    0.5872

>> t2

t2 =

    0.1053
```

it gives me those results (MATLAB 2011). However I tested it in MATLAB 2013, and using sum was worse than the for loop. I don't know whether I messed up or I missed something?

Which is better? for loop or sum?

Comment: Your code is not correct. In `sum1 = sum1 + rand(i);` you are adding a scalar with a matrix of increasing size.

Comment: If you want reliable benchmarking, `tic` and `toc` are generally the wrong choice. Use [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html).

Comment: Aside from the other problems already mentioned, you need to put your statement `r = rand(1e8, 1);`  *inside* the `tic` and `toc` of the `sum` method for a fair comparison...

Comment: it was a typo, it was actually r(i)

Comment: I can not confirm the results using Matlab 2013a, the call of `sum` is faster.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Using `timeit` and with a random seed of `rng(123)` I get  0.364831 seconds with the `for` loop and 0.036971 seconds with `sum`.  I'm using MATLAB R2015a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function timing_builtins()
% Setup
rng(123);
r = rand(1e8, 1);

    function test1(r)
        sum1 = 0;
        for i = 1:1e8
            sum1 = sum1 + r(i);
        end
    end

    function test2(r)
        sum2 = sum(r);
    end

    t1 = timeit(@() test1(r));
    t2 = timeit(@() test2(r));

    format long g;
    fprintf('For loop: %f seconds\n', t1);
    fprintf('Sum call: %f seconds\n', t2);
end
```

This should give you a better view of the speedup, it is about 10 times for `sum` over the `for` in this specific case.

If we call the predefined variable `r` instead, we can see that the built-in `sum` is indeed faster than the `for` loop, with a factor of 4.

Built-ins are almost always the faster choice. The BLAST engine has been overhauled recently decreasing this factor (I used 2012a), but for the exact same operation a built-in will usually be faster. The same holds for vectorising things using `bsxfun`, that'll also be (almost) always faster than using loops.

To cite @beaker:

The answer to the more general question is, "it depends." Sometimes loops are faster because they don't do all of the error checking and type conversions that a generalized built-in would.

Thanks to @Daniel and @rayryeng it seems the call to `sum` is indeed faster still in the newest MATLAB versions. The reason for this is that `sum` requires almost no checks, since there is not much that can go wrong in summing elements. Also the `sum` native calls a function from the LAPACK / SuiteSparse interface, which is highly optimised.

Comment: This does not answer my real question, you are focusing on a typo and getting same results as me. I need to know if for loops implementation changed due updates (2013a or newer), or built-in functions are "always the best choice".

Comment: Just imagine the `for` loop being faster than the built-in `sum`: wouldn't MathWorks instantly change their `sum` implementation to the `for` looped one?

Comment: @dpalma That's really not what your question asks. You ask specifically if `sum` is better than a loop, not if all built-in functions are better than their equivalent loops. The answer to the more general question is, "it depends." Sometimes loops are faster because they don't do all of the error checking and type conversions that a generalized built-in would.

Comment: thanks @beaker. I took the liberty to put that into my answer as well.

Comment: @Adriaan Be my guest. I'm sure there are several answers around with benchmarks comparing loops to built-in or vectorized approaches. If I run across a good one I'll post the link.

Comment: My question was in the context of testing with two different versions of MATLAB, so I explained all the background for answering it. Now I am accepting the answer, since it really address the original question (previously it didn't, at least for me). Thanks P.S: Because everyone focused on a typo, rather than the real issue.