# Why is MATLAB's union function so slow?

Tags: performance, matlab, set

If i want to find the union of two unordered sets, represented as 1D vectors, eg:

```
a = [2 4 6 8 1]
b = [1 2 5 7 9]
```

i can use the union function:

```
c = union(a,b)
```

which gives the answer:

```
c = [1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

however, this appears to be quite slow (relatively speaking). If i run a tic-toc test on it i get:

```
>> for test = 1
tic
c = union(a,b);
toc
end
Elapsed time is 0.000906 seconds.
```

whereas, if i use this much more convoluted method, i get a much quicker result:

```
>> for test = 1
tic
a_1 = zeros(1,9);
b_1 = zeros(1,9);
a_1(a) = 1;
b_1(b) = 1;
c_1 = or(a_1,b_1);
c = find(c_1);
toc
end
Elapsed time is 0.000100 seconds.
```

this still gives the same answer for c, but is about 9 times as fast (with this small example, im not sure about how well it scales)

what is the advantage of ever using union? and can anyone suggest a more compact way of expressing the second method that i used?

thanks

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438242/using-tic-toc-for-benchmark-matlab/33438437#33438437) and associated answer about why some functions are faster than their built-in counterparts.

Comment: To be specific, you can probably save memory and speed it up a bit I think with: `a_1 = false(1,9);
b_1 = false(1,9);
a_1(a) = true;
b_1(b) = true;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several comments:

1. Your code isn't as general as union. You're assuming set members are strictly positive integers.
2. Your code will blow up if a set member has a large value, eg. 10^20, as it tries to allocate an absurd quantity of memory.
3. A bunch of Matlab functions that don't use BLAS/LAPACK or aren't built-in are actually quite slow. They're there for convenience but don't be shocked when you can roll something faster yourself, especially if you can specialize for your particular problem.
4. Representing sets using logical arrays (which is what you do) can be highly efficient for problems where the set of possible set members is quite small.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I didn't take into account that i was only working with positive integers all of relatively low values. When you say `where the set of possible set members is quite small`, how small is quite small? as a general rule, i will only be working with a maximum size of around 500-1000 members in a set, would you count that as small enough to continue using logical arrays?

Comment: If there are 1000 different possible set members, that should be trivial. You can represent a set using 1x1000 array of logicals which, on my machine, takes 1000 bytes = 1 kilobyte.

On the other hand, if your set elements were all possible 10 character words and you had 26^10 possible elements, logical arrays would clearly not work.